# How to sort a 3G bytes access log file?

Tags: shell, sorting

Hi all: Now I have a 3G bytes tomcat access log named urls, each line is a url. I want to count each url and sort these urls order by the number of each url. I did it this way:

```
awk '{print $0}' urls | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr >> output
```

But it took really long time to finish this job, it's already took 30 minutes and its still working.
log file is like bellow:

```
/open_api/borrow_business/get_apply_by_user
/open_api/borrow_business/get_apply_by_user
/open_api/borrow_business/get_apply_by_user
/open_api/borrow_business/get_apply_by_user
/loan/recent_apply_info?passportId=Y20151206000011745
/loan/recent_apply_info?passportId=Y20160331000000423
/open_api/borrow_business/get_apply_by_user
...
```

Is there any other way that I could process and sort a 3G bytes file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If all you want is a count of each URL, then chances are you can do the whole thing using one command. [Edit] your question to show us a sample of your log file and the desired output.

Comment: In case it is really the `sort` command itself that slows the whole thing down you can try the `--parallel=N` option

Comment: It would me much better for you to include the same as plain text, rather than taking a screenshot. Could you do that?

Comment: There are two sort commands, where should add the parallel option and what should N be?  I am using a 4G memory macbook air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using awk at the moment - it's not doing anything useful.

I would suggest using something like this:

```
awk '{ ++urls[$0] } END { for (i in urls) print urls[i], i }' urls | sort -nr
```

This builds up a count of each URL and then sorts the output.

Comment: I guess the reason why its so slow is the file is too large. It's still slow by your way.

Comment: @leo the key is, if Tom's solution is faster than yours. Yours went through the file 4 times, and should be slower than Toms. Also how do you define "slow" "fast" on this task? what is your benchmark?

Comment: @leo this reduces the size of the list you're trying to sort to the number of different URLs, so it stands a better chance of fitting into memory. You're trying to process a reasonably large file, so you can't expect it to be instantaneous!

Comment: @Kent You are right, I am processing a large file and should not judge the method without enough data like processing time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I generated a sample file of 3,200,000 lines, amounting to 3GB, using Perl like this:

```
perl -e 'for($i=0;$i<3200000;$i++){printf "%d, %s\n",int rand 1000, "0"x1000}' > BigBoy
```

I then tried sorting it in one step, followed by splitting it into 2 halves and sorting the halves separately and merging the results, then splitting into 4 parts and sorting separately and merging, then splitting into 8 parts and sorting separately and merging.

This resulted, on my machine at least, in a **very significant** speedup.

[image]

Here is the script. The filename is hard-coded as `BigBoy`, but could easily be changed and the number of parts to split the file into must be supplied as a parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
################################################################################
# Sort large file by parts and merge result
#
# Generate sample large (3GB with 3,200,000 lines) file with:
# perl -e 'for($i=0;$i<3200000;$i++){printf "%d, %s\n",int rand 1000, "0"x1000}' > BigBoy
################################################################################
file=BigBoy
N=${1:-1}
echo  $N
if [ $N -eq 1 ]; then
   # Straightforward sort
   sort -n "$file" > sorted.$N
else
   rm sortedparts-* parts-* 2> /dev/null
   tlines=$(wc -l < "$file")
   echo $tlines
   ((plines=tlines/N))
   echo $plines
   split -l $plines "$file" parts-
   for f in parts-*; do
      sort -n "$f" > "sortedparts-$f" &
   done
   wait
   sort -n -m sortedparts-* > sorted.$N
fi
```

Needless to say, the resulting sorted files are identical :-)

Comment: I tend to go with `i=$(( i + 1 ))` since I learned that [`++` isn't required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). Maybe I'm missing something here but isn't the size of the final `sort` the same anyway?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the increment not being in POSIX, it works on my Mac and I tend to use it. I will update. The merge sort should only read one line from each input file at a time (as all are already sorted) and just hold one line in memory for each input, then output the one first in order, then replace the used up line by doing another read. I figured the sort was using the most RAM - I may be wrong - but it is maybe worth a try.

Comment: Based on [the answers to this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/279096/67817), it would appear that `sort` is probably going to do something similar to your approach under the hood anyway. Thought you might be interested :)

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for that. I guess one could experiment with `/usr/bin/time -l sort` and see.

Comment: @TomFenech Hi Tom. I did some more experiments - maybe you'd care to take a look and comment.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit confused about what you're comparing here. I guess the real measure of difference in performance would be to time manually splitting `BigBoy.csv`, sorting separate chunks and merging vs. sorting it directly?

Comment: Oh, it's ok. I am not suggesting my idea is faster or better - your answer has been selected and it is fine and great. I was just being academic/thorough and trying to see if the merge sort takes less memory - and it does. I presume sorting a 3GB file after splitting it into 750MB chunks will almost certainly require less memory than sorting a 3GB file. So, I am happy that, if memory is the issue, it is worth splitting and merging.

Comment: ...but `sort -m` doesn't do any sorting! From the manual: `merge already sorted files; do not sort`.

Comment: No, but that's ok, I sorted them first - in small chunks using less memory. It just interleaves the sorted data.