# How many times executed bash command

Tags: bash

I have a script that will execute a PHP file multiple times:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$(cat $1)

while IFS= read -r i in $file; do
php x.php "$i" &
done < "$1"
```

the text will be

```
a
b
c
d
```

What should i do to show me the line number that it's using out of how many, for example

`3(current line)/200(number of total lines)`

I did some research but i couldn't find anything.

Comment: What is `$1` you are passing to the script? What is your expected output? Show us a sample snippet

Comment: $1 is the text file. I'm building a php mailer the output should be 4/20 Sent newsletter to email@email.com . All i need is to make this bash script show me the line number and the number of total lines from the text file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the number of lines in the file first using `wc`, then add a counter to the loop. You're redirecting the file to the while loop, so you only need to assign the `i` variable while you read it:

```
#!/bin/bash

len=$(wc -l < "$1")
j=1

while read -r i; do
  echo "$j / $len"
  php x.php "$i" &
  j=$(( j+1 ))
done < "$1"
```

Comment: A little simpler and easier to read maybe... `len=$(wc -l < "$1")` and `((j=j+1))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell or just `echo " $((j+=1)) / $len"` and start at 0.

Comment: @123 True - though I seem to recall being told that `+=` is not POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Looks like it is http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_02_01

Comment: @123 I am not arguing and not unduly worried, but for completeness I was told by Tom Fenech here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835844/2836621 and can see what he means by searching on the page he refers to for `++` here http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes postfix/prefix operators aren't required, it doesn't say anything about assignment operators though.